# Different views based on user type - Correct segue type after login?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, segue

I have a Login View Controller which is the initial view controller. Here users input their username and password, which is then sent off to the server to be checked. If the user has inputted correct credentials the server responds with some JSON data including the user type (either 'student' or 'demonstrator'). I'm using the returned user type to decide on what views the user the will see. (users will see different tab controllers)

The bit I'm struggling on is on what type of segue to perform. Push or Modal? I tried embedding a navigation controller into the Login View Controller and performing a Push Segue to the correct view, but this seems to not play nice with other navigation controllers that are embedded in the other views (title's disappear etc).

Is the modal segue type the correct one to use in this situation? The user wont be returning back to the login screen at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that you **CANNOT** nest navigation controllers. Pushing a navigation controller onto the navigation stack leads to the types of errors you saw with missing titles and the like. Always modally segue to a navigation controller, and use unwind segues to get back if you need to.

A push segue is used exclusively to push the destination view controller onto the navigation stack. The initial view controller must be in a navigation stack before you can push segue. If your login view is the root view of a navigation controller, then pushing the next view is the way to go.

On the other hand, which it sounds like may be your case, if your login view is your initial view and you want to segue to two different navigation controllers containing different paths for different user roles, you'll want to modally segue to the navigation controllers themselves.

Some Reference Material From Apple:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH6-SW1